# Virtual private server security

Tags: webserver, web-hosting

I want to move from a shared hosting to VPS. I never used VPS or dedicated server, so I wanted to know if there are some security precautions that I should have in mind. Say, I create a ftp account or, database user, should I do smth to secure my account info, or it is something that the provider should take care of ?
Also, for example similar to shared hosting, can I restrict the access to my database from specific IP addresss ?

**EDIT**

The server is only for me alone, need to put there my website, so, I should be the the only user. It is a usual php website, with mysql database, no extra services are necessary.

Thanks

Comment: use a web server provider if you don't need anything too fancy it is way more easy to handle. if you want to learn, avoid use it as a production system at the beginning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you move to your own VPS you are the one administering the server so you will have to take care of your own security.

Now this security administration could be difficult or easy depending on how many services or users you allow in, if you are the one using the VPS and you just install a few services for tests purposes and not for production issue you might relax a little, following I will add some basic security considerations you will have to take care:

1. Install a server you really know how to manage (or one you want to learn how to manage). If you don't have the time to learn and you want to keep it secure go for one you already know.
2. Keep your server up to date with security updates.
3. Keep track of the services you are running: ftp, DB, ssh, http server... For each of one you should keep track of the users and the passwords.
4. Stop or remove any service you don't use (the less services, the less problems).
5. From time to time have a look to the user list on your services or to the latest connections to your system if you find anything suspicious try to find the problem and change passwords.
6. Do backups outside the server (this is a life saver).

Long story short, a VPS security is a DIY.

Comment: I do approve, but in case of VPS, the most important thing if it's only for your personnal use is to be more secure than most others, because if bots can't find security leaks, it's unlikely that a single man determine tries to hack into your system.

Comment: thanks @kiBytes for your answer, I updated the question. So, I guess relatively I can relax little ?

Comment: @Davo It is the very same, you can be a bit relaxed (I have my own and I am somehow relaxed with my security, but I do follow those steps to keep track of my server. I recommend you to stick to the bare minimum services.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, and, can I also ask one more question, I know it is a very broad question, but if u can give me some clue, that would be great. As Im on a shared hosting(dreamhost) I can not see the RAM usage, now I have to choose the ram size, my website has about 350 K pageviews a month, will 256 Mb will be about right ? THanks

Comment: That is a question for webmaster.SE or superuser.SE but I believe that if you have a normal landing page and you don't generate a lot of traffic it should be more or less enough (I suggest you to hire the VPS for a month to test it out so if you don't like it you can buy some power-ups).

Comment: traffic is about about 30 GB per month. btw the VPS gives 1000 GB. Thanks